# lodash remove method from an array React

Tags: reactjs

I have a state value of names which is an array. I am having a difficult time understanding how to remove an item using lodashs remove. Looking over the docs I understand to pass in the current array, and then a callback but I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly.

So my method for removing is as follows:

```
removeItem(oldItem) {
_.remove(this.state.names, name => name === oldItem);
}
```

I am attaching this method to a button when I am mapping over all of my names in my array.

```
let test = this.state.names.map((name, index) => {
      return (
        <div>
        <li key={index}>{name}</li>
        <button onClick={this.removeItem(name)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      )
    })
```

Appreciate the help thanks.

Comment: This could be a context issue.  Are you binding removeItem to the component?  If not, then "this" in the removeItem method probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Yes the method is bound within the constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can remove items from React state in that way. You should use setState() method.

Try to do something like this in your "removeItem" method.

removeItem(oldItem) {
const names = _.remove(this.state.names, name => name === oldItem);
this.setState({names:names );
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you need to do

1. You want to bind function to an event, not bind result of a function to an event.

So you should change

```
<button onClick={this.removeItem(name)}>Delete</button>
// This one tell React, when someone click this button, void! (aka. do nothing) because that is the result of 'this.removeItem(name)'
```

To

```
<button onClick={() => this.removeItem(name)}>Delete</button>
// This one tell React, when someone click this button, call the '() => this.removeItem(name)' function
```

2. You'll need _.filter not _.remove because _.remove does not return you with new array, it mutates array and return the removed elements. In most case in react, you don't want mutation, you want a fresh new array to be set in state.

So instead of this.

```
removeItem(oldItem) {
  _.remove(this.state.names, name => name === oldItem);
}
```

Do this

```
removeItem(oldItem) {
  // use filter to get new array without oldItem,
  // and setState it to trigger React render.
  this.setState({
    names: _.filter(this.state.names, name => name !== oldItem),
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks Dopf this was a really understandable response you gave me. Thank you! I will accept this one!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can remove items from React state in that way.

You should use setState() method. Try to do something like this in your "removeItem" method.

```
removeItem(oldItem) { 
  const names = _.remove(this.state.names, name => name === oldItem); 
  this.setState({names:names}); 
}
```

Comment: And really, there are other was to remove a string from a list of strings.  Look up filter or splice